# visual basic changing registry values on runtime

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, visual-studio

Is there a object/code/thing with Visual Basic that can change some registery values (by doing an action like clicking a button(i know how to do that!)) that are not from the program it self? i need the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM` and change `ColorizationGlassAttribute` to 2. 
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`RegistryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.aspx) class has the functionality that you need.

For your stated purpose, you would use it like this:

```
Dim key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                  "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM", True)
If key IsNot Nothing Then 
    key.SetValue("ColorizationGlassAttribute", 2)
    key.Close()
End If
```